# image control not showing image

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, image

**What i Want to Do!**

I want to show an image using image control. The source image is on file directory. The location of file is C:// directory while my project (Virtual Directory) is on D://. I want to set image source at page load.

**What i have Done!**

1. Put image control on my .aspx page.
2. On page load set imageurl to my suggested url

Following is the code I've written

```
    Dim urls As List(Of String) = TryCast(Session("SliderUrls"), List(Of String))
    Dim url As String = urls.Item(4)
    Image1.ImageUrl = url
```

**Note**

url value is assigned properly. There no issue in url. On internet at some websites I've read that asp.net don't allow us to access resources outside virtual directory. So do you think that this may be the problem that i'm facing? and if so then how can i generate url for another virtual directory. Like i have a virtual directory on D://myproject and another virtual directory C://files. How can i generate url for Virtual directory on C://file while working in project which is in Virtual Directory D://myprojec.

Comment: You've answered your own question. Images outside the website directory, or not in a virtual directory, can't be accessed.

Comment: and i also asked how to fix this issue means accessing another virtual directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urls / paths have to be virtual and not physical.

Even though you've made the directory virtual, you appear to be trying to use the physical path instead.

Trying to use the physical path (C:/path) will not work.

Try using the base url of the other virtual directory and build your url from that.

For instance  if the virtual directory is `http://localhost/media`

use that as the base url and attach the resources from there `http://localhost/media/image.jpg`

```
Dim baseUrl as String = "http://localhost/files"

Image1.ImageUrl = baseUrl + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(urls.Item(4))
```

I'm assuming the urls contains only the filenames (`image.jpg` for instance)

you can also store the baseUrl in `web.config` appSettings